# What does `zero scaling` mean? - Ruby context

Tags: ruby, sinatra, microservices, stateless

I'm working through creating a stateless microservice with `Sinatra`
and am reading through something and am seeing that I need to enable my application for `auto-scaling` and `zero-scaling` by telling `OpenFaaS that my function is eligible for zero-scaling`.

What do those two terms mean?

For zero-scaling, it sounds like it has something to be with the application not running when it's not needed or am I way off?

> Let’s define “zero-scale” as the idea that a function can be reduced down to zero replicas when idle and brought back to the required amount of replicas when it is needed. The building block for this exists in most container orchestration systems such as Kubernetes and Docker Swarm. When a Kubernetes Deployment is scaled to zero replicas, its Pod will be deleted.

This was in the link provided below. Not sure what this means.

Does this have something to do with, whenever a function is not needed, that function is pretty much in an inactive state and only called when as needed?

If there is 1 replica of a function, does this mean that it's barely above zero, so whatever process is happening requires very minimal attention needed to trigger an event or something?

Comment: Just googled "OpenFaas zero scaling" and got [this article](https://www.openfaas.com/blog/zero-scale/) which explains it.

Comment: _Auto-scaling_ means that a function can be scaled up or down depending on demand. By default, 1 replica is kept as a minimum so it still consumes resources, even when not needed. _Zero-scaling_ allows going down to 0 replicas but with a twist: as soon as a request comes in for an unavailable function, a replica is started and the request is served afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds more like serverless architecture & there are mutliple offerings from multiple cloud vendors, in terms of AWS try lamda functions, it sounds to me similar to zero loading & spawn instance when request arrives.